# Are the real numbers ever needed to prove a property of the natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory, logic, arithmetic, peano-axioms, foundations

Suppose no one had invented/discovered the real numbers yet (so e.g., no calculus), would this constrain the possible theorems or knowledge we could have about the natural numbers?

Comment: You can ask analytic number theorists, say.

Comment: Did anybody "invent" the real numbers?

Comment: @RobertIsrael So claimed [Kronecker](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/biography/Kronecker.html).

Comment: ... or "discover" them, for that matter.

Comment: You probably need to know a thing or two about real numbers to read through the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, or of the Prime Number Theorem, or of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions, or to think about Riemann's Hypothesis. I guess the answer depends on the meaning of "knowledge we could have".

Comment: To state, e.g., the Prime Number Theorem, you need to define natural logarithms (at least of positive integers), and these are irrational real numbers (except for $\ln(1)$).  Does this qualify as an answer to your question?  Or are you insisting on the whole system of real numbers?

Comment: @RobertIsrael That definitively qualifies, but its not clear to me that we cant make an equivalent statement using only naturals.

Comment: If you want, you might replace every real number by a Cauchy sequence of rationals.

Comment: Right, so likely this question makes no sense, because also, all our symbols are discrete, so any theorem is a theorem about what finite strings we can put together in some finite symbol formal system. But it makes it convenient

Comment: Also, can you replace the natural log $\ln(n)$ by the n-th harmonic sum $H_n$ and prove the prime number theorem - you can now certainly state it.

Comment: The Hasse-Minkowski theorem says that a quadratic equation has a solution in rational numbers (or natural numbers if you like) if and only if it has a solution over every local field over the rationals. So for example, you could construct a quadratic equation and now be able to show that it has a solution over the naturals without knowing the existence of real numbers and p-adic numbers (and solutions over them).

Comment: I think a logician should weigh in here.

Comment: You rang? Oh, that's right; I'm a *terrible* logician... :)

Answer (score 13):

Since we are talking about whether real numbers are *necessary*, it only makes sense to talk about theorems that do not require real numbers merely to state the theorem, since that is a very trivial sense of "necessary".

The properties that can be stated directly in terms of the natural numbers are called *arithmetical* in the literature. These are the properties that are obtained by starting with multivariable polynomial equations over the natural numbers and closing under logical operations and universal and existential quantification over the naturals. Although it may seem as if this is a very limited collection of properties, it turns out after much nontrivial work that many statements can be stated arithmetically (for example, the Riemann Hypothesis, Fermat's last theorem, the Prime Number Theorem, and the statement "$\pi$ is irrational" can all be rephrased as arithmetical statements).

Next, it is also necessary to look at provability in fixed formal theories. After all, if we took every true arithmetical statement as an axiom, this system would be able to prove every true arithmetical statement (trivially) without the use of real numbers. But that is not the point, and it makes the question uninteresting. So we need to specify which set of axioms we are considering for the natural numbers, just so that we have some collection of properties that are *not* provable. The most common axiom system for studying arithmetical statements is first-order Peano arithmetic, PA.

Thus one way of stating the question that is both precise and interesting is:

> Are there formal systems that extend PA by allowing us to talk about real numbers, and which prove every (arithmetical) statement provable from PA as well as additional arithmetical statements?

The answer to that is yes. One example of such a system is Zermelo-Frankel set theory, ZF. This is able to prove every arithmetical statement provable in PA, as well as many more.

It is not necessary to go all the way to set theory. For example, there is a system well known in logic called "second order arithmetic" ($Z_2$) which is a natural system for studying just the natural numbers and real numbers. This system, $Z_2$, is strictly between Peano arithmetic and ZF in terms of the arithmetical statements it is able to prove.

P.S. In terms of the statements I listed above, it is known that PA proves the Prime Number Theorem and that $\pi$ is irrational. It is suspected that Fermat's Last Theorem is provable in PA, although this has not been shown rigorously. And nobody knows if the Riemann Hypothesis is provable even in ZF.